# Access child label control value in Datalist control with multiple records when child LinkButton control is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one aspx page with a Datalist control and a FormView control. The Datalist displays all the records and the FormView is hidden. The FormView displays the details of a record and the Datalist control is hidden. When I click a record in the Datalist I go to the Formview to display, edit the selected record.

How can I pass the record id to the click event to select the record in the database and display the details in the Formview?

There are multiple controls with the same client id and the runtime appends a number to the end to make the client id unique.

Here is the control I want to access from code behind:

```
<asp:Label ID="lHideAndSeek" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IdString") %>' CssClass="hideAndSeek">
```

Here is the control I use to select the company details:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectCompany" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                    onclick="btnSelectCompany_Click"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

Here is the code behind where I want to access the label control when the linkbutton is clicked and pass the value to the SelectCompany() instead of hard coding the 4:

```
protected void btnSelectCompany_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataList1.Visible = false;

    FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.ReadOnly);

    using (jpEntities myEntities = new jpEntities())
    {
        FormView1.DataSource = myEntities.SelectCompany(4);
        FormView1.DataBind();
    }

    FormView1.Visible = true;
}
```

Thanks you for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CommandArgument attribute to your LinkButton and bind it's data, like you did with Text attribute. Then you can extract that value from code-behind.

Something like this.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectCompany" runat="server" 
            CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' OnClick="btnSelectCompany_Click"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></asp:LinkButton>

LinkButton linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
int id = int.Parse(linkButton.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying the command argument with the e parameter before!